# Identify Azure Private DNS Zone entry for Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server

Tags: azure, azure-postgresql, azure-dns

I set up an Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server instance with private access (VNet Integration). It is mandatory to provide a Private DNS Zone which I did. After successfully creating the instance you can find a record inside that Private DNS Zone with a (generated?) name like `a13af2aa1234`that points to the private IP of the instance.

Is there a link like *This record name belongs to this PostgreSQL instance name* that reveals the correlation?

I don't get it why it seems to be generated as the PostgresSQL instance name itself already must be unique (as they prepend that name to `postgres.database.azure.com` as DNS name).

Edit: If I add a second instance I have two entries in the private DNS zone.

[image]

How do I know which record belongs to which instance?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that when the PostgreSQL Flexible server is created within a virtual network with a private DNS zone, the "server name" that you can see in the Azure portal will respond with the private IP.

**tldr:** just use the `{server_name}.postgres.database.azure.com` name and it will resolve to the private IP of the private DNS zone.

---

What happens in practice is that the above name has an `NS` record that points to the "hex" private zone record:

```bash
> dig {server_name}.postgres.database.azure.com NS +short
e4f33bc2df77.{server_name}.private.postgres.database.azure.com.
```

Resolving the domain (the one without `private` in it) leads you to the "hex" domain with a `CNAME` and then to the actual IP address.

```
> dig {server_name}.postgres.database.azure.com

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
{server_name}.postgres.database.azure.com. 26 IN CNAME e4f33bc2df77.{server_name}.private.postgres.database.azure.com.
e4f33bc2df77.{server_name}.private.postgres.database.azure.com. 26 IN A 10.0.1.4

...
```

If this is documented somewhere, I don't know where that is, though.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the right answer on how to resolve the postgresql via dns when using private access. This is literally mentioned no where. It took me hours over hours figuring out that you don't need the hex private zone record for connecting to Postgres.

Comment: Your explanation is correct but does not answer my question, though. Suppose I create 100 instances, then I have 100 "unknown" hex records in my DNS Zone. Using external tools like `dig` is the equivalent of connecting to the database behind the record and checking what is inside. I want to see a static link in the console/cli/terraform. I hate this part of Azure.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a link like *This record name belongs to this PostgreSQL instance name******?**

**Yes**, its interrelated to Vnet and DNS zone integration where we allow the traffic.

[image]

Vnet subnet range.
[image]

When Private DNS zone integration is required to connect to your Flexible Server in virtual network using server name (fully qualified domain name).  The DNS records for the server name will be updated automatically in case the IP address of your Flexible Server changes.  [Learn more](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2161990)

Replicated the same scenario
[image]

[image]

[image]

refer this [tutorial](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/dns-configuration-patterns-for-azure-database-for-postgresql/ba-p/2560287) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but it does not answer my question. If I add a second instance of Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server I will get a second entry in the private DNS zone. Now I have two entries with a random record name and I do not know which of these belongs to which instance.

Comment: both entries under DNS zone relates to subnet IP ranges of Vnet. One entry will be created by the time of DNS Zone creation, another one if we add manually new IP address will be populated with respect to the subnet IP ranges. see this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/dns-configuration-patterns-for-azure-database-for-postgresql/ba-p/2560287

Comment: _both entries under DNS zone relates to subnet IP ranges of Vnet_ **yes**  
  
_One entry will be created by the time of DNS Zone creation, another one if we add manually new IP address will be populated with respect to the subnet IP ranges_ 
 **no**: I create the Private DNS Zone manually. Then I create two instance of Postgres pointing to that manually created zone. Now I will get two records with random names. Each record has the IP of **one** of the instances. The questions always was: which record belongs to which instance.

Comment: use this command in powershell to verify which Ip it was consuming. "Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <*****postgres.database.azure.com>"   It's already mentioned in above mentioned link under "Access from another VNET using peering."

Comment: I appreciate your creativity @SwarnaAnipindi but this does not answer my question. I am looking for link between the record and the instance on a configuration level. Like an App Service App knows to which App Service Plan it belongs by providing a link in the console overview. I do not use Windows, so PowerShell is not an option and going through the DNS is a technical way (matching the IP to the record). I want to stay on configuration level. The answer may well be _Does not exist_

Comment: refer this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking#private-access-vnet-integration   An A record (Address Record) points a domain or subdomain to an IP address.

For example, an A Record is used to point a logical domain name, such as "google.com," to the IP address of Google's hosting server, 74.125.224.147.  Refer this for in detail https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/dns-records-explained.

Comment: mcont's answer is the right one

Answer (score 1):

The link you are looking for can actually be found in Azure DNS.

You are never supposed to use the cryptic hex DNS names in your private DNS zone. Instead, use the FQDN of your database as shown in the portal or with `az` cli.

Assume you have an Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server `my-server` in resource group `example`, and your private Azure DNS zone is `my-zone.postgres.database.azure.com`

Run

```
 % az postgres flexible-server show -n my-server  -g example -o json --query 'fullyQualifiedDomainName'
"my-server.postgres.database.azure.com"
```

to get the FQDN.

Note: nowhere in the output of `az postgres flexible-server show` you are going to find that hex-gibberish DNS name that was created in your private zone.

However, if you lookup your flexible server FQDN, for example with the `host` command, you will find that it is an alias for the entry in your private DNS zone.

```
# host my-server.postgres.database.azure.com
my-server.postgres.database.azure.com is an alias for de12af34.my-zone.postgres.database.azure.com.
de12af34.my-zone.postgres.database.azure.com has address 10.10.0.4
```

So here's the link between your flexible server an the cryptic DNS entry in your private zone. But the best thing is, you don't really need to worry about this link. Just use your flexible server's FQDN and you're set.

NOTE: when using PostgreSQL flexible servers with delegated VNETs and private DNS zones, the FQDN can only be looked up from within Azure.

Comment: Everthing else in Azure has neat connections in the state stored in CLI/Terraform. I consider the DNS records resources that where created based on the commands. So I wonder: why is there no configurational connection? As you already mentioned I need DNS name resolution in place where I really don't need it in my opinion.

Comment: And it is not discoverable through Azure web portal. I always need additional tools.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure portal, go to your Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server resource and look at the **Connect** page.

You'll see the FQDN for your database in the **Connection details** section:
`export PGHOST=mydb.postgres.database.azure.com`.

[image]

This works because the database name `mydb` is globally unique.

In the DNS, `mydb.postgres.database.azure.com` has a CNAME record that points to the 'hex' record that you mention in your question. This is an implementation detail; you shouldn't ever use the 'hex' record directly, only the FQDN given to you on the **Connect** page.

Comment: Thank you for the effort but that was not the question. I was looking for a way to identify the record not connect to my database.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Yes it is a mystery, there's no way to find out which hex name corresponds to which server other than by doing a forward lookup of the database's name in the public DNS.